# Error: Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug my custom SharePoint page but I'm getting the following error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is runing and connected to the SharePoint farm.

I don't know what's causing this error.

What might be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you need to give **db_owner** permissions to the account which you are using to deploy the custom SharePoint solution for all the SharePoint related databases.

**Follow the below steps to assign the permission:**

Open the DataBase,
expand **Security -> Logins ->** right click on the account and go to properties.
Then in the properties window, click on User Mappings from the left side.
Then you can select the database and select the permission as **db_owner** as shown in the fig below and click on OK.

For details steps refer to the below article :

[[Solved] The local SharePoint server is not available. Check that the server is running and connected to the SharePoint farm.](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/the-local-sharepoint-server-is-not-available/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check the ULS log so you could find the detailed information.

SharePoint 2013

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

SharePoint 2016/2019

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS